# Passing methods dynamically to child component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have separate components for each of the different form types in my Vue app (Radio Buttons, Text Field, Checkboxes, etc). I use these components across my app to cut down on code and design time.

I already pass down data to these components, but I wanted to know how I could dynamically pass down different methods triggered on different event listeners. Here is an example of what I am doing:

```
//SelectField.vue
<template>
<select>
  <option v-for="(option,key) in options" value="'{option}'">{{option}}</option>
</select>
</template>

//ParentExample1.vue
<template>
<div>
  <select-field @change="doThis" @click="doClickAction1"/>
</div>
</template>

//ParentExample2.vue
<template>
<div>
  <select-field @change="doThat" @click="doClickAction2"/>
</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via [$listeners](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-listeners). At the very basic level add `v-on="$listeners"` to your element you want to pass down listeners to:

```
<select v-on="$listeners">
  <option v-for="(option,key) in options" value="'{option}'">{{option}}</option>
</select>
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vuejs-starter-bze7z9) in action.

For it to work with `v-model`, you may need to take additional steps which is documentated well with an example in [Custom Events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components). Something like:

```
<template>
  <select v-bind="$attrs" v-bind:value="value" v-on="selectListeners">
    <option v-for="(option,key) in options" value="'{option}'">{{option}}</option>
  </select>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "SelectField",
    inheritAttrs: false,
    props: ['value', 'options'],
    computed: {
      selectListeners: function () {
        const vm = this;

        return Object.assign({}, this.$listeners, {
          input: function (event) {
            vm.$emit('input', event.target.value)
          }
        });
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Usage:

```
<SelectField v-model="value" :options=“myOptions” @change="someHandler" @click="anotherHandler" />
```

Here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-le2nz) of `v-model` with the custom component in action.

Hopefully that helps!